# Bash reverse search gets stuck after a single symbol

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

When I use the reverse search functionality of bash, oftentimes it gets stuck after entering a single symbol. For example, if my history is:

```
username dir$ scala -version
username dir$ git status
```

and then I press `Ctrl + R` and type in `s`, it gets stuck at

```
(reverse-i-search)`s': git status
```

Typing further symbols does nothing. Any idea on why does that happen?

Some information that might be relevant:

PS1:

```
\u \[\033[0;35m\]\W\[\033[0;37m\]$
```

bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

OS:

```
macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.2
```

Terminal:

```
iTerm2
```

Comment: Is it possible that you typed Ctrl+s instead of s? Does Ctrl+q clear it?

Answer (score 2):

Because the search program found the `s` at end of `... status` and is now looking for another command that also ends with `... status`, which is does not find.

You can confirm this theory using `<ctrl-R> + d` instead of `<ctrl-R> + s`. Then the search will find the `d` of `username d`, and will continue the search from there, and e.g. will straightforwardly go "up" to `username dir$ scala -version`.